# NumberFormatException when using substring()

Tags: java, substring

I'm attempting to determine whether or not a string is made up of sequential integers using the code below. However, it throws a NumberFormatException when I run it.

I have determined this is caused by using the variable i as the index values for substring().

This has really frustrated me as I cannot find another way to do it. Does anyone know why substring() cannot use variables as index values and what I could do to fix/ circumvent this issue? (other than using a giant if statement ) Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

```
public  static void main(String[] args) {

    String x = "12345";
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(0, 1)) == (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(i, i++))) - i) {
            counter++;
        }  
    }

    if (counter == 5) {
        System.out.println("String is sequential");
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from anything else, you probably shouldn't be incrementing `i++` *inside* the loop. Do you mean `x.substring(i, i+1)`?

Comment: don´t use `i++` on `x.substring`, you are incrementing it afterwards, which should be the loops job. Just do `i+1` and only loop until `x.length -1 `

Comment: But, you can just use `Character.getNumericValue(x.charAt(i))`.

Comment: Paste the whole stacktrace and I'll answer your question. What's more, I'll learn you solve such problems by yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x.substring(i, i++)` is the same as `x.substring(i, i)` (as far as the values passed to `substring` are concerned) which gives an empty String. Calling `Integer.parseInt` on an empty String gives `NumberFormatException`.

To fix your current loop :

```
for (int i = 1; i < x.length(); i++) { // note the range change
    // using (i,i+1) instead of gives you a single character
    if (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(0, 1)) == (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(i, i+1)))-i) {
        counter++;
    }  
}
```

Or, you can avoid using `substring` at all. Simply iterate over the characters of the `String` :

```
for (int i = 1; i < x.length(); i++) {
    if (x.charAt(0) == x.charAt(i) - i) {
        counter++;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(0, 1)) == (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(i, i+1))) - i) {
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to extract a substring and then parse it back to an integer.

```
Character.getNumericValue(x.charAt(0)) == Character.getNumericValue(x.charAt(i))
```

would do the same, provided all of the characters are digits. In the case that the characters aren't digits, it wouldn't throw the `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
     (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(i, i++)))
```

this will return empty string , you need to make it ++i